# Make very small, (or large), exponential calculations

Tags: c++, math, 32-bit, exponential

Exponential limit of most 32 bit machines is

```
exp( +/-700 )
```

But I would like to do an exponential calculation

```
res = exp( x ) / exp( d )
```

when x or d are bigger than 700 I use the fact that

```
exp( x + y ) = exp( x ) . exp( y )
```

So my calculation would be something along the line of

```
res = (exp( x - z ).exp(z)) / (exp( d - z ).exp(z))
```

or

```
res = exp( x - z ) / exp( d - z )
```

where (x-z) < 700

But this approach is flawed in some cases, for example where x = 6000 and d = 10000
If we use z=5300 then

```
res = exp( 6000 - 5300 ) / exp( 10000 - 5300 )

res = exp( 700 ) / exp( 47000 )
```

But exp( 47000 ) = 0 on a 32 bit machine.

If I replace z = 9300 then I get the opposite effect.

```
res = exp( -3300 ) / exp( 700 )
```

So how could I solve the above equations, (that should return a 32bit valid number I think), given the limitations of the computer?

**Edit**
The reason for doing this is I am using the formula

```
P( a ) = P(y1) * P(y2) * P(y3) ... P(yN)
```

In order to prevent overflow I then do

```
a = log( P(y1) ) + log( P(y2) ) +  log (P(y3)) ... log( P(yN) )

b = log( P(z1) ) + log( P(z2) ) +  log (P(z3)) ... log( P(zN) )

...

z = log( P(zz1) ) + log( P(zz2) ) +  log (P(zz3)) ... log( P(zzN) )
```

to get a total I do

```
total = a + b ... z
```

and to calculate the percentage I do

```
(exp(a) / exp( total ) ) * 100
```

but it is possible that "a" and/or "total" are greater than 700

I guess the question could be how could I calculate the percentage without using the exponential

Comment: you do realize that `exp(x-y) = exp(x)/exp(y)` which would mean that `exp(6000)/exp(10000) = exp(-4000)`, which is past the limitations

Comment: I cannot really follow you math. `exp(x) / exp(d)` with `x=6000` and `d=10000` is `exp(6000-10000)=exp(-4000)` and this wont produce overflow

Comment: Search internet for "Big Number Library C++".

Comment: What is the context of this computation? Usually, when extremely large numbers appear in the numerator and denominator of a fraction, but the fraction itself is readily representable, it is time to re-order the math. If you think the math cannot be re-arranged, you could add an additional scale factor to each of your operands, creating a custom "uber-float" format with two exponents.

Comment: I added some more information to my question to hopefully give more details.

Comment: That is not a whole lot of additional information. Are the `P()` probabilities? Is the high-level question something like: "How do I avoid underflow in Bayesian computations?". If so, there are likely answer to this available on Stackoverflow or elsewhere on the internet, and this question would be an example of an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thanks all, I ended up going for a Big Number Library, (ttmath for now, but I might change it).
The numbers always convert back to a c++ double, (they have 2), so I just need to calculate big/small exp() before doing a simple division.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter that the answer should be a 32 bit number if some of the intermediate steps in the calculations aren't.

For math that goes outside the bounds of an int or long type, you probably need to start using something like GMP.

https://gmplib.org/

Comment: I dont really agree with the "doesn`t really matter" part, because (as mentioned in a comment by njuffa) in many cases, the math can be rearranged to avoid overflow also in intermediate steps.

Comment: There are many situations where intermediate terms can overflow or underflow floating-point formats when using naive translation from a textbook formula that can be resolved by re-arranging the math rather than switching to an arbitrary-precision library, e.g. computing the ratio of factorials or gamma functions, or attempting to compute `exp(x*x) * erfc(x)`.

Comment: I completely agree with you, as njuffa mentioned, I am just trying to find a way to re-arrange my calculation(s) to maybe prevent the need for a third party library.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want to compute this:

```
p = exp(a) / exp(b)
```

And since `a^b/a^c == a^(b-c)` this reduces to

```
p = exp(a - b)
```

which can be easily computed **if** that difference is below that critical exponent.

If it isn't, then your result cannot be represented by primitive datatypes like `double` (because it's either extremely large or extremely small), you then need some kind of arbitrary precision numbers, probably provided by some library.

**But if you only need to print the result, or store it somehow, then you can easily compute even extremely large numbers:**

For that, you change to base 10 (for displaying), compute the equivalent exponent therefore (`tExponent = log10(eExponent)`), and get that value into the allowed range between `std::numeric_limits::max_exponent10` and `std::numeric_limits::min_exponent10`, saving the difference as scaling factor.

For now, I just have a [quick and dirty live example](http://ideone.com/WvKLJG), showing

```
exp(90000) / exp(100)  =  1.18556 scaled by 10^39043
```

([Check at wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e7ruq4mafjn))

---

*Note: When I wrote this, it was pretty late in the evening. I'm leaving this here for an "alternative" approach.*

Now, generally, there's

```
a^b = [a^(b/c)]^c
```

And since

```
(a/b)^c = (a^c)/(b^c)
```

[holds, too](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ersu072r6de), I guess the easiest approach here is to just divide both exponents as long as one of them is above your critical value, then do the exponentiation, divide the results, and finally use the divisor of the former exponents as exponent for the quotient:

```
double large_exp_quot(
    double eNum,
    double eDenom,
    unsigned int const critical = 200) {
  if (abs(eNum - eDenom) > critical) {
    throw out_of_range{"That won't work, resulting exponent is too large"};
  }
  unsigned int eDivisor = 1;
  while (abs(eNum) > critical or abs(eDenom) > critical) {
    eNum /= 2;
    eDenom /= 2;
    eDivisor *= 2;
  }
  return pow(exp(eNum) / exp(eDenom), eDivisor);
}
```

But this will only work, if the result of your computation can actually be stored using the C++ primitive datatypes, in this case `double`. The example you gave ... with exponents 6000 and 10000 ... is obviously not representable with a `double` (it's `e^(-4000)` and thus incredibly small)

Comment: Thanks for the code, this will help me a lot, I chose to use a math library in the end as they can do the heavy lifting efficiently.

Comment: Depends on how much you need to work with these values afterwards, as I said of you only need to print (or compare) them then this simple code won't be slower than using some sophisticated library.

Answer (score 2):

Numerically unstable computation: exp(a) / exp(b)
Equivalent stable computation: exp(a - b)

Numerically unstable computation: Π<sub>i=1..n</sub> p<sub>i</sub>
Equivalent stable computation: exp(Σ<sub>i=1..n</sub> log(p<sub>i</sub>))